# Excel: Include value in range based on value in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say i have a table1 with 2 columns [COUNTRY] and [NAME].

**COUNTRY | NAME**
NL | John
NL | Peter
NL | Karin
BE | Jack
BE | Tom

In table2 column1, I have a dropdown (data validation list) that contains the unique values from the [COUNTRY] column. Let say I select "NL" in that dropdown in row1, I want to create another dropdown in table2 column2 that only contains the NAMES from table1 that with COUNTRY = "NL": so {John, Peter, Karin}.

When I change the value in the dropdown in table2 column1 to "BE", the values in the dropdown in table 2 column2 should now change to {Jack, TOM}.

Any solutions, or pointers in the right directions? I'm lost...

Comment: There is a solution to this problem here: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Comment: well, this is not really what I'm looking for since it requires separate 1-column lists for all options, whereas i have 1 single 2-column list.

Comment: Well the second column is dependent on the first in the example I've signposted you to, and so is yours

Answer (score 1):

Table 1, put in F1:G6

In B1:C1, enter output header : "Country" and "Name"

In B2 >> Data Validation >> "Allow", choose : `List` and "Source", enter : `NL,BE`

In C2 >> Data Validation >> "Allow", choose ; `Custom`  and "Source", enter :

```
=OFFSET($F$1,MATCH(B2,$F$2:$F$6,0),1,COUNTIF($F$2:$F$6,B2))
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But what happes when the COUNTRY column F is not ordered? After "BE | TOM", maybe i have to add "NL | Danny". Is there also a solution for an non-ordered source list?

Comment: The OFFSET formula must use sorted data, if the source data come in unsorted, you could use the Excel build-in Sort function to sort the data prior the entry of Data Validation formula. The other solution is using INDIRECT function as per the linked website in the upper level "Comment" by Plato 77, but you need to break in several columns.